# How can I use one view for one controller in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I m new to ASP.Net Core and I m trying to build a project and I want to make only one view (lets call it CreateOrEdit). I have this simple model but I don't know where to start from

```
public class test
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string sname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
```

}

This could help but don't knock how to build a view for it
// Copyright © 2015 Dmitry Sikorsky. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0. See License.txt in the project root for license information.

```
using ExtCore.Data.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Platformus.Configurations.Backend.ViewModels.Configurations;
using Platformus.Configurations.Data.Abstractions;
using Platformus.Configurations.Data.Entities;

namespace Platformus.Configurations.Backend.Controllers
{
  [Area("Backend")]
  [Authorize(Policy = Policies.HasBrowseConfigurationsPermission)]
  public class ConfigurationsController : Platformus.Barebone.Backend.Controllers.ControllerBase
  {
    public ConfigurationsController(IStorage storage)
      : base(storage)
    {
}

public IActionResult Index()
{
  return this.View(new IndexViewModelFactory(this).Create());
}

[HttpGet]
[ImportModelStateFromTempData]
public IActionResult CreateOrEdit(int? id)
{
  return this.View(new CreateOrEditViewModelFactory(this).Create(id));
}

[HttpPost]
[ExportModelStateToTempData]
public IActionResult CreateOrEdit(CreateOrEditViewModel createOrEdit)
{
  if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    Configuration configuration = new CreateOrEditViewModelMapper(this).Map(createOrEdit);

    if (createOrEdit.Id == null)
      this.Storage.GetRepository<IConfigurationRepository>().Create(configuration);

    else this.Storage.GetRepository<IConfigurationRepository>().Edit(configuration);

    this.Storage.Save();
    return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

  return this.CreateRedirectToSelfResult();
}

public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
  this.Storage.GetRepository<IConfigurationRepository>().Delete(id);
  this.Storage.Save();
  return this.RedirectToAction("

Index");
    }
  }
}
```

[Ref](https://github.com/Platformus/Platformus/blob/master/src/Platformus.Configurations.Backend/Areas/Backend/Controllers/ConfigurationsController.cs#L29so)

,

Comment: why only one? maybe 2: Create and edit? and probably item list? just use scaffolding to generate controller and views

Comment: what was on my mind is something similar to webforms, where you can perform all operations (CRUD) in one view or in that case form.

Comment: you can look at SPA: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Razor Pages` might be what you are looking for, check this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/index?tabs=visual-studio). also this [link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2017/B8048) might help you understanding the concept.

Comment: Would using an API fit my sinario?

Comment: `API Controller` would [work too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api).